# jQuery.hover causing blinking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two images, one of which is very small and is superimposed over the other.  When I hover over the larger image, the second image should appear on top of it.  This works great.  Unfortunately, when I move my mouse over the smaller image (which, remember, is on top of the larger image), the screen blinks wildly.  The system thinks I am leaving the larger image when I am actually not.  Let me post some code.

```
<li id="li-{{ photo.id }}">
    <div class="photo-container">
        <img class="photo" src="{{ photo.thumbnailFile.url }}"/>
        <img class="delete-button" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}delete_photo.jpg "/>
    </div>
</li>

function DisplayPhotoOptions() {
$("#personal-photo-list .photo").hover(function(event) {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    $(this).next(".delete-button").css("visibility", "visible");
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
    $(this).next(".delete-button").css("visibility", "hidden");
});

(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
         DisplayPhotoOptions()
    });
    })();
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cursor is leaving larger image because `.delete-photo` is not its child.

Try binding `hover` to `.photo-container`.

Comment: ahhhh I think you got it.  Let me try it out.  I forgot why I made photo-container in the first place.